# How to close a Record producer displayed in a GlideDialog after records gets submitted

Tags: servicenow

I have a servicenow Record producer which is display as a content of a GlideDialog.

My Record Producer has a Submit button which user press when user as completed data entry.

Once submit is done, the content of GlideDialog window is set to the redirect url define in Record producer settings.

I have tried to close the GdlideDialog from a html button which is outside the Record producer content, and if click my close button I can close the GlideDialog window without trouble

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<j:jelly trim="false" xmlns:j="jelly:core" xmlns:g="glide" xmlns:j2="null" 
xmlns:g2="null">

<g:evaluate var="jvar_url" 
expression="RP.getWindowProperties().get('url_param')">
</g:evaluate>

<button id="close" onclick="closeAck()" 
type="button">$[gs.getMessage("Close")]</button>
${jvar_url}
<div>

<iframe id="rp_frame" src="${jvar_url}" width="800" height="600">
</iframe>

</div>
<script>

addLoadEvent( function() {
onLoadFunction();

function closeAck() {
alert("CLOSE ACK REACH");
GlideDialogWindow.get().destroy();
    }
});
```

What i try to do is to close the GdlideDialog windows after user press the Submit button of my record producer

If I inspect in my browser the html code of the submit button it appears as below :

```
<button type="button" id="submit_button" name="submit_button" 
class="request_catalog_button header_button btn cat-btn btn-primary" 
href="#" onclick="saveProducer('');" title="" aria-label="Submit" data- 
html="true" role="button" data-original-title="Submit">
        Submit
        <span class="sr-only">Submit</span></button>
```

What is a possible way to close the dialog right after submitting record producer data using script and where to place that script ( Ui Action, Ui page, Record producer ?

Thanks for advise

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but you could try this: 
window.onunload = function() { window.close()"; };